# jQuery add() function and the context of jQuery objects

Tags: jquery, object

Given the following HTML example...

```
<div id='div1'>div one</div>
<div id='div2'>div two</div>
```

...I found that the following jQuery code...

```
$('#div1').click(function() {

    var $d = $(this);    // Using 'this' instead of '#div1'

    $d.add('#div2').remove();
});
```

...would not add `#div2` to the set referenced by `$d`, but this code...

```
$('#div1').click(function() {

    var $d = $('#div1');    // Using '#div1' instead of 'this'

    $d.add('#div2').remove();
});
```

...successfully added `#div2`.

Upon consulting firebug, I found that using `$(this)` gave the jQuery object a context of `#div1`, but doing `$('#div1')` gave the object a context of `document`.

Given this information I tried...

```
var $d = $(this, document);
```

...and the `add()` function worked as expected.

So here's the question. Could someone please explain to my why a different context is assigned when using `$(this)` vs `$('#div1')`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Edited to better address your question:
[First, look at the relevant code here](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L59), this is how jQuery handles the `$()` call.  When you're passing a DOM element (which `this` is, it's the div itself) the context is the DOM element itself, this better allows handling of document fragments, etc.  When you pass a string, the default context is `document` (because it's the top ancestor to search from).  Remember a `$(selector, context)` is actually calling `context.find(selector)` under the covers, so it makes sense to start at document if nothing's specified.

*Note:*  you can always check the context, it's an available property, like this: `$(this).context`

For the [`.add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) behavior:
`.add()` uses the same context for selecting as the jQuery element you're adding to, so what you're seeing is the expected behavior.  For a better description, [see how `.add()` is written](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/traversing.js#L114):

```
add: function( selector, context ) {
    var set = typeof selector === "string" ?
                jQuery( selector, context || this.context ) :
                jQuery.makeArray( selector ),
                all = jQuery.merge( this.get(), set );

    return this.pushStack( isDisconnected( set[0] ) || isDisconnected( all[0] ) ?
            all :
            jQuery.unique( all ) );
    }
```

Note how it uses the current context if none is passed.  To override this though, it accepts a context, to which you can pass `document` and get the result you want, like this:

```
$('#div1').click(function() {
   $(this).add('#div2', document).remove();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think maybe I'm just not understanding the purpose/use of the context of a jQuery object. Why does `$d` have a context of `#div1` in the first place instead of `document`?

Comment: @patrick - You can see how `$(this)` is handled here: http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L59  When you do `$(DOMElement)` the context is that DOM element, just how it works.  For example, you could be dealing with an element that's not in the DOM, in a document fragment for example, so `document` doesn't always work.

Comment: @patrick - I re-read your post and re-wrote most of the answer to better address your main question, hopefully that clarifies it a bit more, let me know if it still leaves questions.

Comment: OK, I think I'm getting it. So the reason jQuery assigns `#div1` is that jQuery doesn't really know what the heck else to put there (without doing a traversal every time, I suppose). So overriding the context in `$d` is safe and irrelevant in terms of expected functionality.