# Chaining the JQuery object [$(this)] and other objects

Tags: jquery

How do I chain the jQuery object with another object such as this:

```
($(this) AND $('#foo')).hide();
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`.add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/)

```
$(this).add('#foo').hide();
```

**EDIT**

Interestingly enough, you can't start with "this". Must be something to do with the element. That having been said (and for now) use the following:

```
<a href="#">Hide both</a>
<div id="foo">
    Additional content to hide
</div>
$('a').click(function(){
    $('#foo').add(this).hide();
});
```

Proven to [work](http://www.jsfiddle.net/bradchristie/z5Pn9/). Meanwhile, I'm going to see what I can find about why the previous version doesn't work.

Comment: @lolCoder: I'm noticing that. Yet, the docs say it should work. Hold on, working on it.

Comment: @Brad: It is because of a strange issue relating to the context of the object being added to. I had [a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2626494/jquery-add-function-and-the-context-of-jquery-objects) about this a while back.

Comment: @patrick dw: That actually, in a weird way, makes perfect sense. I'd even go so far as to not call it a bug so much as an undocumented feature. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @Brad: Yeah, I probably shouldn't have called it an issue. More like an unexpected behavior. I actually forgot about it when I voted on your original answer. Your edit reminded me.